# how to import functions with aws lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using `api gateway` to call a post request into my `lambda` which checks if the `httpMethod is post`, if post then do the following.

by default the entry point is `index.js` which I kept but then I am thinking if I am using the same `lambda`, I can also check if it's a `get httpMethod`, if so then do the following.  But I want to separate my codes. Which I see for the same `lambda` function, I can add files.  So I tried to add another file named `post.js` then require at `index.js`

Somehow, it's not passing values or calling the exported function in `post.js` though.

`index.js`

```
  const postHandler = require('./post.js');

  exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
      try {
          const httpm = event.context["http-method"];
          const rbody = event["body-json"];

          console.log(postHandler, 'post handler function?');  // { postHandler: [AsyncFunction] } 'post handler function?'
          console.log(httpm, 'httpmhttpm');  // 'POST'

          if (httpm === 'POST') return postHandler(rbody);
      } catch (e) {
          return e;
      }

  };
```

`post.js`  // not doing anything special here, but none of these console shows up

```
exports.postHandler = async (rbody) => {
    console.log('I am inside postHandler()');
    console.log(rbody);

    return {status: true};
};
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / help.

Comment: excuse me, yeah. The problem is the wrong import

Comment: `const { postHandler } = require('./post.js');`

Comment: @AlexOwl oh my my~ how can I miss that darn!

Comment: we are so tired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// default export (change post.js file)
module.exports = async (rbody) => {
    console.log('I am inside postHandler()');
    console.log(rbody);

    return {status: true};
};

// OR !

// change (index.js file)
const { postHandler } = require('./post.js');
```